# Concatenating a value onto the end of an object property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, concatenation

I'm saving user preferences using localStorage, like this:

```
 choicesObject = {          //put values in an object
    "measure1"      : $("#m1").is(':checked'),
    "measure2"      : $("#m2").is(':checked'),
    "measure3"      : $("#m3").is(':checked'),
    "measure4"      : $("#m4").is(':checked'),
    "measure5"      : $("#m5").is(':checked'),
    "measure6"      : $("#m6").is(':checked'),
    "measure7"      : $("#m7").is(':checked'),
    "measure8"      : $("#m8").is(':checked')
}
localStorage.setItem("choices", JSON.stringify(choicesObject));
```

Then I'm getting them back out like this:

```
retrieveChoices = localStorage.getItem("choices");
choicesObject = JSON.parse(retrieveChoices);
for(var i = 0;i<9 ;i++){
```

This nex t line is the problem:

```
    ticked = choicesObject.measure+i;
```

It just doesn't work and I've tried using quotes and square brackets.

```
    element = "#m" + i;
    if(ticked==true){
        $(element).prop('checked', true);
    }
    else{
        $(element).prop('checked', false);
    } 
}
```

}

I want to loop though the measure properties and restore the checkbox elements.

I'm aware that even my object create is inefficient and I could use a for loop for that but I just don't know how to deal with object properties when it comes to looping because I don't get how you can do it without breaking the object.

At least that works and I can get data into and out of objects that get stored in localStorage, but this really simple issue has me stumped.

PS. Would

```
choicesObject = localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse("choices"));
```

be a better shorthand? Just thought this now whilst re-reading my question.

Edit: Thanks everyone. I got 3 correct answers so quickly! Amazing. Thanks so much. This site and its members amaze me every day and have revolutionised my coding!

I'm going to choose the correct answer as the one that also gave me the new shorthand for my parsing, but all of you gave me what i needed to know. I'm going to go see if I can answer some noob questions now!

Comment: Try `ticked = choicesObject["measure"+i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ticked = choicesObject["measure"+i];
```

---

EDIT: Your shorthand would not work, use instead:

```
choicesObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("choices"));
```

Answer (score 1):

An object is just like a "dictionary" of values, so you can access a property either by doing `myobject.propertyName` or `myobject["propertyname"]`. They are equivalent.

In your case you just have to replace `ticked = choicesObject.measure+i;` with

```
ticked = choicesObject["measure"+i];
```

Also, consider using the `var` keyword when defining variables, each time you ommit it a new global variable will be created in the window object, that is the case for `retrievedChoices` and `choicesObject`. You can confirm this by accessing them via `window["choicesObject"]` or `window.choicesObject` or just `choicesObject` anywhere after that script has run.

Comment: Thanks Rui. I actually want these to be global objects.